# Removing old kernels

Tags: kernel, purge

I used this command

```
echo $(dpkg --list | grep linux-image | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'`uname -r`'/q;p') $(dpkg --list | grep linux-headers | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([0-9.-]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/q;p') | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

from  this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) to remove old kernels to free up the disk space, but while executing that command I get the following message

```
...
1 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 2 to remove and 288 not upgraded.
Need to get 52.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 186 kB of additional disk space will be used.
...
```

Shouldn't this command free up the disk space instead of using additional disk space ?

Comment: Did you try: apt autoremove?

Comment: `sudo apt autoremove`

Answer (score 2):

Didn't you do:

```
echo $(dpkg --list | grep linux-image | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'`uname -r`'/q;p') $(dpkg --list | grep linux-headers | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([0-9.-]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/q;p') | xargs echo sudo apt-get -y purge
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................^^^^
```

first?

Seriously, use the `/usr/bin/purge-old-kernels` script (part of the `byobu` package)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i

CONFOLD=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')

KERNELCUR=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')

PKGLINUX="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"

PKGMETALINUX="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"

KERNELSOLD=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $PKGLINUX |grep -vE $PKGMETALINUX|grep -v $KERNELCUR)

apt-get purge $CONFOLD

apt-get purge $KERNELSOLD

apt-get autoremove
```

To free up more disk space you can continue running:

```
apt-get install --reinstall deborphan

deborphan

apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)

deborphan --libdevel

apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)

deborphan --find-config

dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)

apt-get autoremove

apt-get clean
```